# How can I print abstract page immediately after TOC or before it?

Tags: page-breaking, abstract

How can I print `abstract` page immediately after `TOC` or before it  independent of place of `abstract` environment in document?

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}
\def\keywords{A, B, C, ...}
\newenvironment{abstract}{\pagenumbering{alph}%
        \chapter*{Abstract%
            \vspace*{-20pt}%
            \markboth{%
                \MakeUppercase Abstract}{\MakeUppercase Abstract}}%
}{\section*{keywords:}\keywords\newpage}%

\author{AAAA}
\title{my booooook}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
%abstract here
\chapter{chap 1}
\section{sec 1}

\begin{abstract}
this is the book abstract
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you need `\MakeUppercase{Abstract}`...

Comment: There is a semi-generalisation of this question: I want to code some text at an arbitrary place in the source and have it printed in a different arbitrary place in the output; but then there is: I might want to have it output in one place or perhaps another. The first is doable by creating a macro for the text at some point in the source and than calling it at another place in the source. The second is, I think, up to the author. I would prefer the source to be ordered in the same manner as the typed output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the abstract as a `\chapter*`, which issues a `\cleardoublepage` (since `openright` is true, by default) right before it sets the chapter heading. This "double page clearing" necessarily forces the chapter to start on a recto (right) page, leaving an empty (verso) page, if needed.

You can avoid this by momentarily setting `\newpage` to `\relax` (a no-op) while setting up your abstract. Here's one such an attempt that stores the content of the abstract in the `.aux` file (as `\abstractbody`), which is then retrieved and used immediately after `\tableofcontents`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{extbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{environ}

\def\keywords{A, B, C, \ldots}
\newenvironment{abstract@toc}{%
  \clearpage
  \pagenumbering{alph}% Reset page numbering
  \begingroup
  \let\newpage\relax
  \vspace*{-20pt}% Move chapter title up
  \chapter*{Abstract}% Set abstract chapter
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{Abstract}}{\MakeUppercase{Abstract}}%
  \endgroup
}{\section*{keywords:}\keywords\newpage}%

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{abstract}{\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\abstractbody{\BODY}}}
\makeatother

\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \oldtableofcontents
  \begin{abstract@toc}
    \csname abstractbody\endcsname
  \end{abstract@toc}
}

\author{An author}
\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what I looking for. because changing  place of `\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{abstract}` to end of document, the abstract page  place changes too.

Comment: @C.F.G: Okay. So let's be clear then: You want to place the `abstract` at the end of the document within the code. Correct? Where do you want the actual abstract to appear in the document output? Also, where should the abstract appear within the ToC?

Comment: Yes. and in output immediately after Toc or before it.

Comment: @C.F.G: Could you define the abstract in the preamble?

Comment: Sorry for delay. if there is no way, no problem.

Comment: @C.F.G: I've just updated my answer to store the contents of your `abstract` environment in the `.aux` file (since you want to write the abstract *after* it should possibly appear in the document output). It'll take at least two compiles with every change in the abstract to reflect the changes within the output.

Comment: Thank you so much. A small question: why `\begin{abstract@toc}` works out of `\makeatletter`?

Comment: @C.F.G: The argument of `\begin` (and `\end`) is processed using `\csname`...`\endcsname`, which doesn't require the `@` to be in a different category code.